# Regular expression to exclude particular pattern match

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for matching telephone no but not "**[1398340387]**" --[10digits] pattern

I have this regular expression to identify phone no but this is also matching [1398340387] which i want to escape.

```
1?\s*\W?\s*(\d{3})\s*\W?\s*(\d{3})\s*\W?\s*(\d{4})(\se?x?t?(\d*))?
```

Context:

I have a string that can possibly contain phone no(s) and [1398340387]: unix time stamp and i need to highlight all the phone nos if found. Right now Unix time stamp is also identified as phone no and highlighted and I need to avoid this.

**Sample string**

> [1398337818] *** Conversation started *** with 'yash' [1398337818]
>   sam: Telephone no :  1-234-567-8901 1-234-567-8901 x1234
>   1-234-567-8901 ext1234 1 (234) 567-8901
>   1.234.567.8901 1/234/567/8901 12345678901 [1398337818] sam: hello [1398337905] sam: credit card 1111-2222-3333-4444 [1398338242]

What should i add to escape the later part?

Thanks

Comment: In what context are you using this regex? Can you just do that check separately?

Comment: Can you show us a sample string?

Comment: @Mokchhya Do you also want to capture the `EXT` (ext1234) ?

Comment: @Tuga: His regex does capture the extension, so I suspect the answer is yes.

Comment: Seems like you could use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ignore numbers that are enclosed in `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will match only phones in your sample:

```
\b1\s*[-/\.]?\(?\d{3}\)?\s*[-/\.]?\d{3}[-/\.]?\d{4}(\s+(x|ext)\d{4})?\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BkpNI82qmveF1bCE)